# My scanner methods aren't working and the while-loop won't break

Tags: java, if-statement, exception, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm a beginner and don't know what is wrong with my program.

What I would like the program to do is to allow the user to enter an Integer that is under MAX (1 000 000 000) but above 0. I also have put an exception block using the `try` and `catch` methods so that the user cannot enter a String.

The exception block works but it also prints the statements inside the `if` block, which I don't want.

This is what the console prints:

```
Number of marbles to divide: 
*three*
Please enter a number not a word
Try again: 
Please enter a number under 1 000 000 000 and above 0
Try again:
```

I only want it to print... `Please enter a number not a word Try again:` after the user enters a String. What I mean is that I want the method's while-loop to break if the user has entered a string.

Another problem that I can't seem to solve is that if the user enters an Integer that's value is over MAX (1 000 000 000), the program continues. This is what the console prints.

```
Number of marbles to divide: 
1000000001
Number of people:
```

As you can see the program continues even though the user has entered an Integer over MAX (1 000 000 000)

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MarblesApp
{
    final static int MAX = 1000000000;
    static int  numberOfMarbles;
    static int numberOfPeople, marblesPerPerson, marblesLeftOver;
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the marble divvy-upper.");
        System.out.println("This program will tell you how many marbles to give to each person.\n"
    + "The maximum amount of marbles is 1 000 000 000. The maximum amount of people is the same.\n");

        System.out.println("Number of marbles to divide: ");
          numberOfMarbles = GetMarbles();

        System.out.println("Number of people: ");
          numberOfPeople = GetPeople();

        marblesPerPerson = (int)numberOfMarbles / numberOfPeople;
        marblesLeftOver = (int)numberOfMarbles % numberOfPeople;

        System.out.println("Give each child " + marblesPerPerson + " marbles."); 
        System.out.println("You will have " + marblesLeftOver + " marbles left over.");
    }
private static int GetPeople()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            return input.nextInt();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException f)
        {
            input.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter a number not a word\nTry again: ");
        }

        if(numberOfPeople > MAX || numberOfPeople == 0);
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number under 1 000 000 000 and above 0\nTry again: ");
        }
    }
}
public static int GetMarbles()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try 
        {
            return input.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            input.next(); 
            System.out.println("Please enter a number not a word\nTry again: ");
        }

        if(numberOfMarbles > MAX || numberOfMarbles == 0);
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number under 1 000 000 000 and above 0\nTry again: ");
        }

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Try to write the question to the point and not as essay.

Comment: Maybe the console returns "123\n" instead of "123" to the program, try a different parsing method.

Comment: Everything you read from stdin will be read as a string only, unless it is parsed by the scanner into the corresponding datatype/object. So you can't know what scanner has read unless it parses it.

Comment: Guys, if you aren't willing to take the time it needs to read a request for help from someone who's just learning Java and posts his first question ever on this platform, then you should better move on to the more advanced issues that drop in.

It took me five minutes of reading + another 5 Minutes of code review to know how to help Dylan.

Comment: Pro-tips for posting technical questions on the internet: (1) titles should be a succinct description of the problem, (2) questions should not beg volunteers for help, and (3) there is no need to apologise for being a beginner, everyone has to start somewhere. I think the core question is quite good, it just needed a bit of trimming - see my edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know how difficult Java can be if you're absolutely new to it. And as I'm not one of those who expect your questions to be perfectly written and brought to the point, I assembled a solution to your problem.

I had to reorganize and squeeze your code a little bit. And I have to make some remarks referring to cleaner code:

- method-names in Java always start with a lower-case letter, _ or $
- avoid global variables if you don't need them
- avoid duplicate methodes that only differ in their names

I hope this code gives you a good start into JAVA. Have fun!

```
import java.util.*;

public class MarblesApp
{
    private final static int MAX = 1000000000;

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int numberOfMarbles, numberOfPeople, marblesPerPerson, marblesLeftOver;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the marble divvy-upper.");
        System.out.println("This program will tell you how many marbles to give to each person.\n"
    + "The maximum amount of marbles is 1 000 000 000. The maximum amount of people is the same.\n");

        System.out.println("Number of marbles to divide: ");
          numberOfMarbles = getNumberFromConsole();

        System.out.println("Number of people: ");
          numberOfPeople = getNumberFromConsole();

        marblesPerPerson = (int)numberOfMarbles / numberOfPeople;
        marblesLeftOver = (int)numberOfMarbles % numberOfPeople;

        System.out.println("Give each child " + marblesPerPerson + " marbles."); 
        System.out.println("You will have " + marblesLeftOver + " marbles left over.");
    }

    public static int getNumberFromConsole()
    {
        int number;

        while (true)
        {
            try 
            {   
                // get the number from console
                number = input.nextInt();

                // validate whether it's greater zero and lower MAX
                if(validateNumber(number) == true) 
                {
                    // if true, return the number
                    return number;
                } 
                else
                {
                    // if not, input again
                    input.next(); 
                }
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number not a word\nTry again: ");
                input.next(); 
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean validateNumber(int number) {

        if(number > MAX || number == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number under 1 000 000 000 and above 0\nTry again: ");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate you concern